# Why does the tag `20.10` Even exist If it is off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags, scope

Why does the tags of the releases who have met there end life even exists for eg -

[20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.10)

[19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/19.04)

[16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04)

What are the point of still using these tags ? When all the questions about them are off topic , I have never seen A question with this tag to be on topic most of them are just off topic So it would be much better if we remove these tags **or change the description of these tags** , So that people will thing before asking questions.

What do you think ?

Also I saw that most questions asked with this tag are not marked as off topic,  However  Help centre says that these questions are off topic here.

Comment: Questions about old releases were not off-topic when asked ;-)

Comment: Should I close this question ?

Comment: What kind of a link you are asking for? You can see the date when a question was asked. A question about 20.10 is off-topic now, but wasn't off-topic last year ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're slightly confused about the timing.

20.10 may be End of Life and offtopic *now* but it **was** on topic at the time.  We can update the tag description (and people do do that regularly) and mark it's offtopic, but it's also in the Help Center what we do about 'end of support' releases.  We also tend to *keep* the tags and update their descriptions when they go end of life, but keep the tags because *older* questions still have them.

We also don't close questions posted about releases that *at the time* were on topic - we tend to comment though about whether or not a release is offtopic if new answers, etc. happen on them.  However, a little patience is still helpful here.

Comment: Ok ! :) But atleast change there description and give a warning ( something like "Note 20.10 has reached the end of life so questions about them are off topic" ) When they're asking questions, And it would be good if you change the tags description :) , Again no hurry

Comment: @AkshajSingla You shouldn't delete your question and you shouldn't worry much about the downvotes, as votes in meta don't affect your reputation and in general have a different meaning than they do in the main site. Here they tend to show agreement/disagreement with a post and not with it's quality, as they usually do in the main site. Related: [What is the point of voting in meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14531/618353)

Comment: @Algnis Your idea is a good feature, isn't @Thomas?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy ?? Which idea ?

Comment: @Algnis https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19777/why-does-the-tag-20-10-even-exist-if-it-is-off-topic/19778?noredirect=1#comment43143_19778

Comment: Yeah, I don't think so it is done yet @VScode_fanboy

Comment: @Algnis *done*? What do you think is done? Commenting something as *even do x, but no hurry* won't implement this feature, you have to post a feature-request at https://meta.stackexchange.com.